# How to dynamic count range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
|3|5|0|4|0|9|6|
```

I want to count dynamic count value and not count if value 0.

Example.

1. count  2 time range A1-G1  Result is 5.
2. count  3 time range A1-G1  Result is 4.
3. count  4 time range A1-G1  Result is 9.

how to coding in excel.

Comment: I think it's really difficult to do with a single formula, but could do it easily with a helper row if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 1 in A2, fill this formula across from B2 onwards to number the cells:-

```
=IF(B1,A2+1,A2)
```

and use this formula to look up the value corresponding to the position in A4:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A1:$G1,MATCH(A4,$A2:$G2,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.  if i want to  change count to sum. 
 In my Ex. 
sum 3 time range A1-G1 Result is 12.
How to coding ?

Comment: I would just add another helper row in (say) row 3 using the formula =sum(a$1:a1) and use the same lookup but changing $a1:$g1 to $a3:$g3.

Comment: Or you could do it with a single formula =SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:G1,MATCH(A4,A2:G2,0)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INDEX` function to move across a range of values:

`=IF(INDEX(A1:G1,0,A4)=0,INDEX(A1:G1,0,A4+1),INDEX(A1:G1,0,A4))`

Where `A4` is the count. **However** if the result of the range is 0, it will move to the next, this will only work with a single instance of 0. So one after another would result in 0.

A more full proof solution is to use VBA, here is a custom function for this:

```
Public Function DynamicResult(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal Count As Integer) As Integer

Dim i As Integer: i = 1

For Each cell In Rng

    If (i = Count) Then
        If cell > 0 Then
        DynamicResult = cell
    Else
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
End If

i = i + 1

Next cell

End Function
```

If you paste this code into a VBA module you can use it like so:

`=DynamicResult(A1:G1,7)`